# How can I log every ssh/local-terminal command for all users chronologically?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh, terminal

For example, if a someone has ssh access and his/her history is shown below, I want to log it.

```
1 cd ~/
2 vim file1.txt
3 rm file1.txt
```

I do not care as much about which user, as much as I care about simply logging it and in the order of when it was executed.

Comment: The history is already logged to a file, on bash you can find it in `~/.bash_history` for example.

Comment: Have a look at auditd